# why run time error ! SIGFPE?

Tags: c++

> 4 of the samples shows ok.. Others are not running !
>
> Problem Link: https://www.hackerearth.com/challenge/competitive/programming-indiahacks-2017/algorithm/hacker-with-prime-bebe28ac/

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long   N,A[100000],Q,X[10000],R,p;
     cin>>N>>Q;
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        cin>>A[i];
    }
    for (int i=0;i<Q;i++){
        cin>>X[i];
    }
   for (int i=0;i<Q;i++){
        R=0;
        bool isprime=false;
         for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
         R = (X[i]/A[j])*A[j];

         if (R==X[i])
         {
            for (int k=2;k<=R/2;k++)
            {
                if(R%k==0){
                    R=0;
                };
            };
            if(R==0){
            cout<<"YES"<<endl;
             isprime=true;
                break;
            }
            else {
                isprime=false;
            }

         }

         }
         if(isprime==false){
          cout<<"NO"<<endl;
         }
          }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the link doesn't work...

Comment: please dont ask the questions from live contests

Comment: SIGFPE is a floating point exception. And there isn't much more we can help you with with the question in this state.

Comment: why use `R = (X[i]/A[j])*A[j];` instead of `R = X[i] - X[i] % A[j]`? That saves a multiplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My psychic powers suggest you have input that will trigger your code to attempt to divide by zero.

For example:

```
R = (X[i]/A[j])*A[j];

if(R%k==0){
```

If `A[j]` is zero in the first line, or if `k` is zero in the second line... that might be the cause....